# log4j doesn't write file on windows

Tags: java, javafx, log4j

I'm having problems with my program on Windows, I included logging, so that I can find the specific cause of the issue. My program's JavaFX and to start it on windows I build it as .jar file.

I'm setting up a log4j FileAppender through program code, in the config-file (.../MyProject/data/configuration.txt) is the path where to have the log folder. On Mac OS X (debugged with Eclipse) everything is working fine.

If i'm starting the jar on Windows (.../MyProject/build/dist/MyProgram.jar) and see the configured log folder, i don't see any log file created. (I figured out that the config file than has to be under .../MyProject/build/dist/data/configuration.txt) If i write new subfolders to the log directory's path, the program creates them, but there's no file!

My code:

```
String computername = "";
        try {
            computername = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int tid = (int)Thread.currentThread().getId();
        PatternLayout playout = new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}; %p; %F:%L; " + computername + "; " + tid + "; [%t]; %m;%n");

        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        Date datenow = new Date();
        datenow.setTime(datenow.getTime());
        FcManagerMain.formatteddate = dt.format(datenow);

        try
        {
            File config  = new File ("data/configuration.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/configuration.txt"));   
            int count = 1;
            String line = null;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(count == 3)
                {
                    FcManagerMain.logfolder = line;
                }
                count++;
            }

            if(isWindows())
            {
                File p = new File(FcManagerMain.logfolder + FcManagerMain.version);
                p.mkdirs();
                File pp = new File(FcManagerMain.logfolder + FcManagerMain.version + "\\" + FcManagerMain.formatteddate + ".log");
                pp.createNewFile();
                FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(playout, pp.getAbsolutePath(), false);
                loggerstatic.addAppender(fileAppender);
                loggerstatic.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            }
            else
            {
                File p = new File(FcManagerMain.logfolder + FcManagerMain.version);
                p.mkdirs();
                File pp = new File(FcManagerMain.logfolder + FcManagerMain.version + "/" + FcManagerMain.formatteddate + ".log");
                pp.createNewFile();
                FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(playout, pp.getAbsolutePath(), false);
                loggerstatic.addAppender(fileAppender);
                loggerstatic.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            System.out.println(getStackTrace(ee));
        }
```

loggerstatic is a static Logger instance (FcManagerController.loggerstatic) and every other class takes its logger from loggerstatic. I guess that's not correct, please tell me how to do!

EDIT: I have already tried different log locations to see if I don't have permission to write to that specific folders.

Thanks,
rapgru

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather recommend you use the built-in configuration, i. e. adapt the log4j.properties.

Read the [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm), especially the usage of `${log}` here:

```
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
```

You declare your own system variable by default and change it via jvm parameter when you start your app:

```
# log directory (default, 'log' directory relative to the execution path)
# you can override the default directory by setting the variable as VM option when you start the application
# example: -DMYAPP_LOG_DIR=/tmp/logs
MYAPP_LOG_DIR=./log

...
log4j.appender.debugfile.file=${MYAPP_LOG_DIR}/application.log
```

Then when you start your application and don't want the log file to be in the execution folder, just specify a different path via the `-D` option.

Comment: Thanks, I will try configuring log4j by a property file